# ContextMenu.PlacementTarget is nothing in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, contextmenu, datacontext

I am trying to bind the ContextMenu to ViewModel's commands. After some online search, I learned that since ContextMenu doesn't belong to the target visual tree, I need to specify the DataContext of ContextMenu explicitly using for example, Tag and PlacementTarget.Tag. The UIElement I am attaching the ContextMenu to is a WindowsFormsHost. I don't know whether that's a problem, I will explain why I said that later. My xaml looks like this:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="myHost1" Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
  <WindowsFormsHost.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" x:Name="test">       
      <MenuItem Header="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
...
```

But this code just simply doesn't work.

I put some names to the UIElements so I can check them in the code-behind. And here is what I found: `myHost1.Tag` is correctly assigned to my ViewModel, which has the correct command. However, the `DataContext` of my ContextMenu object is nothing which means my second binding doesn't work. Then when I checked `test.PlacementTarget`, I surprisingly found out that it is nothing. No wonder the second binding doesn't work.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget.aspx), the `PlacementTarget` property is "UIElement relative to which the ContextMenu is positioned when it opens." So to my understanding when I check `test.PlacementTarget`, it should return myHost1 which is of type `WindowsFormsHost`. But why it is nothing?

I said I don't know whether `WindowsFormsHost`is special, since it holds some WindowsFom controls which are rendered differently than WPF. For example, `myHost1` is actually hosting a `AxPivotTable` which has its own context menu. I had to do some extra work to make my WPF context menu visible and hide `AxPivotTable` context menu. On the other hand, when I put a ContextMenu object to the parent of myHost1, which is a `StackPanel`, the `PlacementTarget` is still nothing, which seems to suggest it is not WindowsFormsHost's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try a different approach, and have your `DataContext` for your whole window as a `StaticResource` in your Windows.Resources. Then your command binding would look like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="Save" 
        Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}, Path=SaveCommand}" />
```

Comment: For one thing, this is not a context menu in MainView. It is from a UserControl, and the ViewModel is created on the fly. In fact ViewModel has inheritance hierarchy so I can't store it as a static resource.